# How can I make an extension for extracting keys of a Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am working on this code for making a extension for making key array, but I am unable to give generic type to my array, what I should do for fixing?

```
    extension Dictionary {

    func extractKeys() -> Array<T>  {
        
       return self.map({ $0.key }).sorted(by: { $0 < $1 } )
    }

}
```

update:

```
extension Dictionary {
    
    var extractSortedKeysV2: [Key] where Key: Comparable {
        
        return self.map({ $0.key }).sorted(by: { $0 < $1 } )
        
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct Dictionary<Key, Value>` is a generic type where `Key` is the type of the keys, and `Value` the type of the values. So you'll want to return `Array<Key>` (or just `[Key]`).

In addition, in order to sort the keys, you have to require that `Key` conforms to the `Comparable` protocol:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: Comparable {
    func sortedKeys() -> [Key]  {
        return self.map({ $0.key }).sorted(by: { $0 < $1 } )
    }
}
```

This can be simplified to

```
extension Dictionary where Key: Comparable {
    func sortedKeys() -> [Key]  {
        keys.sorted()
    }
}
```

Or as a computed property:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: Comparable {
    var sortedKeys: [Key] { keys.sorted() }
}
```

In the case of the function/method, the constraint can be attached to the function declaration instead:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func sortedKeys() -> [Key] where Key: Comparable {
        keys.sorted()
    }
}
```

That is not possible with computed properties.

Comment: Interesting, keys are hash-able but it does not mean they are  Comparable? right? also I want use map. not keys!

Comment: @mimi: Yes. Hashable requires Equatable, but not Comparable.

Comment: @mimi: That would be `return self.map { $0.key }.sorted(by: <)` but I do not see any advantage.

Comment: I do not know guts of keys, but I am sure apple use map for that as well like me

Comment: @ Martin : I have a mini question also, how can put () away from sortedKeys() ? can we make it possible? computed property?

Comment: @mimi: Sure: `var sortedKeys: [Key]  { keys.sorted() }`

Comment: thanks Martin, your code work, how could I make my new update work as well? I what use that form. could you plz see the update, thanks

Comment: @mimi: You cannot add the constraint `where Key: Comparable ` to a computed property, you have to add it to the extension declaration.

Comment: @ Martin, Danke schön!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do it yourself. There's a property in `Dictionary` called [`keys`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/keys) that act like an array and contain all the functionality you expect from an array including sorting.

Comment: I know that, i want write an extension. thanks for help